# Launch process with realtime scheduling without root in WSL2

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running Ubuntu 20.04 from within WSL2 I would like to be able to use realtime scheduling as a normal `audio` group member. Ultimately this is for JACK. Everything works as root but this is not ideal.

I have

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf
# Provided by the jackd package.
#
# Changes to this file will be preserved.
#
# If you want to enable/disable realtime permissions, run
#
#    dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd

@audio   -  rtprio     95
@audio   -  memlock    unlimited
#@audio   -  nice      -19
```

Using the configuration checker at https://github.com/raboof/realtimeconfigquickscan I see that I am unable to 'prioritise processes with chrt'. So to debug the problem I'm trying something simple...

With my normal user I try

```
$ chrt -f 80 echo success
chrt: failed to set pid 0's policy: Operation not permitted
```

But as `root` I get

```
# chrt -f 80 echo success
success
```

I wondered if this was due to group RT scheduling. I have

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us
1000000
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
950000
```

which I think are the default values. The same settings work OK on a native install of Ubuntu 18.04 I have running on a different machine.

Nevertheless, I've seen a few places suggest doing

```
sysctl -w kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=-1
```

to effectively turn it off. But this didn't work.

When I first started down this path I didn't really expect JACK to work in WSL2 but the fact that realtime scheduling works as root makes me hopeful this is a configuration/permissions issue rather than a limitation of WSL2. What should I try next?

Comment: *"hopeful this is a configuration/permissions issue rather than a limitation of WSL2"*.  You may have a misunderstanding about the scope and utility of WSL.  It's only intended for the purpose of bringing bash and command line utilities to Windows. WSL is simply the wrong tool for the job. It is not intended to be used for this purpose:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Comment: @Nmath Ha ha, yes I fully appreciate that this isn't what Microsoft had in mind. But, the fact that it does work as root suggests it could work when not root. And if it works and solves a problem that, at the moment, other approaches don't, then I'm happy to use it.